# svg on codepen has scrollbars can't get rid of it

Tags: html, css, svg

I don't know how to get rid of the scrollbars on my codepen example could someone please have a look at my SVG and CSS and see if you can remove the scrollbars without disrupting the image that's been generated. I need the image to fit without the scrollbars somehow there is overlapping I think

[codepen](https://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/KjQRbg?editors=0010)

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 800" width="100%"> 
  <defs>
    <pattern id="hexagons" width="100%" height="100%" >
      <g id="svg" fill="black" x="0" y="0"></g>    
    </pattern>
    <mask id="hexagon-halftone-mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" >  
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#hexagons)" />

   </mask>
  </defs>

  <image width="100%" xlink:href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/07/11/37/tropical-1651426_960_720.jpg" mask="url(#hexagon-halftone-mask)"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: you can start by changing the viewbox to `0 0 500 280`

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you know how to make the spread of the hexagons better so that there is less pink and more hexagons

Comment: it's all about this part `let r = R * Math.cos(angle)` that is creating a consinus curve which is a wave from 1 to 0  ... try to use for exampe `let r = R * 0.8` and see that you will have a linear effect or you can add something like `let c = Math.sin(angle);
    let r;
    if(c<0.6)
      r= R*0.6
    else
      r = R * Math.sin(angle)` . if the  value is lower than 0.6 we don't go smaller

Comment: I guess a fiddle is better: https://jsfiddle.net/46o2rf7d/

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you know how to rotate the hexagon so the point is at the top

Comment: yes, when drawing the polygon you switch cos with sin: https://jsfiddle.net/46o2rf7d/1/ ... but good luck to fix the position :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif viewbox being 0 0 500 280 doesn't remove the scrollbar

Comment: @Salix I know, it just remove the extra space at the bottom without hexagon

Comment: @TemaniAfif which line is the line to change the angle of the hexagon

Comment: the loop of the points `for (var a = 0; a < 6; a++) {` inside change the cos by sin and sin by cos

Comment: But then you need to change y+= and x+= values in the for loops so they align properly.

Comment: Might not help with your current problem, but if you are dealing with a pattern, then you don't need to repeat all these elements yourself, let the <pattern> do its job: https://jsfiddle.net/d6rc9tg3/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to get rid of the scrollbars but you also need the image to fit.

For the 1st part you just gotta add :

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to your body CSS. This will hide the scrollbars but wont prevent your svg to have a bigger height than the window and overflow.

So, for that you want to add :

```
svg {
   max-height : 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

(I put the width there instead of in the HTML code because it makes more sense to me but you can also leave it there and just add the max-height)

Edit : max-height is optional depending on the size/ratio of the picture in your project. It does mean that after a point your image could be smaller than width of the screen. But without it, in your current codepen the image would grow higher than the height of the frame.

Edit 2 : [codepen link](https://codepen.io/salixdubois/pen/BgvRRR?editors=0101) with adjustable hexagon sizes, min size and spacing.